# Taylor Polynomial and limits

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

I think I understand what the Taylor polynomial is, but its application in the calculation of limits is not clear to me.
For example $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(e^x-1-\sin x-x^2)}{\sin^2x}$$
why do we develop the Taylor polynomial's to degree 2 of each funcion here? 
The explanation I gave myself is this:
$e^x=1+x+x^2/2+o(x^2)$, because $e^x-1-x-x^2/2$ tends to 0 faster than $x^2$ 
$\sin(x)=x^2+o(x^2)$ because $\sin(x)-x^2$ tends to 0 faster than $x^2$
So if we add this terms we obtain $$e^x-1-\sin x-x^2=1+x+x^2/2+o(x^2)-x^2-o(x^2)=3/2x^2+o(x^2)$$
But this not convince me at all

Comment: $\sin x=x+ o (x)$

Comment: @SineoftheTime though $\sin x=x+ o (x^2)$ would be more useful here

Comment: @Henry noted and added in my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Since we have $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{sinx}{x}=1$$so the problem become $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^{x}-1-sinx-x^{2})}{x^{2}}$$We know that we have$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{o(x^{2})}{x^{2}}=0$$by defination, and that's the reason that we develop the Taylor polynomial's to degree 2

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: @SineoftheTime i just illustrate the reason why use the Taylor polynomial to degree 2, and that is his question

Answer (score 0):

Your expansion for the sine function is wrong, the correct one is $\sin x=x+o(x^2)$. So the numerator becomes:
$$e^x-1-\sin x -x^2= 1+x+x^2/2+o(x^2)-1-x-x^2+o(x^2)=-\frac12x^2+o(x^2)$$
So your limit is:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-x^2/2+o(x^2)}{x^2+o(x^2)}=-\frac12 $$

Comment: Or even $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)}{x^2 +o(x^2)}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}-\dfrac12+o(x^2) = -\dfrac12$